# How to find questions where I've not accepted an answer

Tags: support

It says that I've accepted 99% of the answers and for the life of me, I can't find the question to which I've not accepted the answer. I've gone to my profile and gone through the list of my questions with no luck.

How to find questions where I've not accepted an answer?

Comment: I see you found the [culprit question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885401/html-decode-asp-net-mvc-string/9885488#9885488) - nice! FYI questions that are less than three days old like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947333/extract-object-into-solr) does not count towards the accept rate so you have 100% - same for questions without any answers.

Comment: Also, you don't _have_ to accept all answers - if, for one of your questions, none of the answers are good enough, don't accept them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Stackoverflow search box type

```
hasaccepted:0 user:177416
```

You will find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947333/extract-object-into-solr) which has no answers. BTW you can see your user ID by clicking on your user profile. The ID is in the search box then.

Comment: You can also use the word `me` instead of your user ID.

Comment: General search documentation : http://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: You might want to add `answers:1` to find only questions with at least one answer as noted in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3138/5701

Comment: Believe it or not, took me until now to accept the answer on the linked question! I must have forgotten about that question and this answer.